# NullPointer When compressing bitmap image

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get an image from gallery or take one using camera in android. taking one using camera app works so fine but getting an image from gallery returs a nullpointer when compressing. below shows my code for sellecting from gallery and camera

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @NonNull Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST1) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

            File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

            FileOutputStream fo;
            try {
                destination.createNewFile();
                fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            image_String = SessionManager.encodeTobase64(thumbnail);
            Log.d("bm", image_String.toString());
            profile_pic.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE1) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,
                    null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap bm;
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 //         options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
 //         BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
            int scale = 1;
            while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                    && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;
            options.inSampleSize = scale;
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
            image_String = SessionManager.encodeTobase64(bm);
            Log.d("bm", image_String.toString());
            profile_pic.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my mothhod to perform the encoding of the imgage i just got

```
public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap img){
    Bitmap image = img;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

    return imageEncoded;
}
```

can't figure out the encode method signals an error when compresing the bitmap taken from gallery of device. Please help me out

Comment: Your problem is very common in picking bitmap from Gallery, you can refer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718138/null-pointer-exception-when-grabbing-picture-from-gallery)  and refer to this [class](https://gist.github.com/Mariovc/f06e70ebe8ca52fbbbe2)

Comment: thanks for you comment @ZhangXiang but i have gone through the post but cant really find why i get the error when trying to encode the image from galley as the method implies.

Comment: Add LargeHeap:true in Manifest activity